clang++ and g++ Compiler gives different output when printing char pointer
clang++ and g++ Compiler gives different output when printing char pointer
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char** argv){
  char a = 'a';
  char* aptr = &a;
  std::cout << aptr << " : " << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

when I compile the code using g++, it gives me the output:
a : a

but when I compile using clang++, it gives me the output:
a�w�� : a

what I think is that the values ahead of 'a' in the output of the clang compile are garbage values.
One more thing, a pointer should store the memory address if I am not wrong. Then why, in this case when I print the memory address of the char, it gives me the character itself?
I am using wsl and these are the compiler versions that I used to compile the code:
Ubuntu clang version 18.1.3 (1)

g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0


When you pass a char* to the output operator, it will expect a null-terminated string. Your "string" isn't null-terminated, so the output operator will go out of bounds and give you undefined behavior.

Your code has undefined behaviour. std::cout << aptr  : here aptr is supposed to point to a null terminated string, but it doesn't....

Enable -fsanitize=address and you'll get an error. std::cout has custom behavior for character pointers, it treats them as pointers to null-terminated strings.

std::cout << (void*)aptr << " : " << a << std::endl;

You're not printing the memory address (that might be what you are trying to do). You are printing a pointer. Normally printing a pointer prints the memory address, but char pointers are special. When you print a char pointer C++ assumes that you are trying to print a null terminated string. This is for historical reasons, in C the only kind of string you had was a null terminated string, and so char pointers are sometimes assumed to be pointing at these.

The operator<<(const char*) that you're using takes a null-terminated string. But you pass aptr, which is not a pointer to a null-terminated string.
That's Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen. Different results are to be expected.
